# How to access the ARM cache memory of RaspberryPI?

Tags: hardware, cache

I would like to enable or disable portion of ARM L2 's cache memory of raspberry PI. I am working on performance evaluation of raspberryPI by locking the cache memory of it. Please suggest me some ideas on this.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the following to your `/boot/config.txt` file. Here is the [source page](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig).

```
disable_l2cache=1
```

> disable_l2cache   disable ARM access to GPU's L2 cache. Needs corresponding L2 disabled kernel. Default 0

But I think for this to actually work, you will need to compile a custom kernel. So replace your `kernel.img` with your custom one, which has the L2 cache disabled. Also have a look at [berryboot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) which allows you to install different versions of the same Linux on your SD card.